# Switching to cout from printf - Complex format specifier patterns

Tags: c++, c, printf, cout

I have to rewrite a logging system in C++ as part of project requirements (everything has to be C++ instead of C now), and there are a number of ways in which we log things like mathematical data and pointer addresses. It is fairly common to see a log like:

```
log("%3.4f %d %zp %5.8f", ...);
```

In C++, using `cout` instead of `printf`, it seems a bit more of an involved process to setup such a logging format, eg, taking the following snippet from C++ Primer Plus (Prata):

```
ios_base::fmtflags initial;
initial = os.setf(ios_base::fixed); // save initial formatting state
os.precision(0);
os.setf(ios::showpoint);
os.precision(1);
os.width(12);
```

This looks like it will set the width and precision for **all** floating point items in the argument list, and won't allow me to have different values for different variables.

Can `cout` even generate such a string in a simple manner with just one line of code, or should I use `sprintf` to prepare my strings and then feed them to `cout`?

Thanks!

Comment: the web page: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/iomanip.html (a much too long a page to post here) describes how to format output for cout

Comment: @user3629249 That's exactly what I was looking for. If you can re-write that comment as an answer, I'll gladly mark it "accepted". Thanks!

Comment: `printf` is available in C++. Why not keep your logging mechanism? Switching to `std::cout` makes sense only if you need its features like overloading the `<<` operator for classes.

Comment: @MOehm Agreed on both counts, but a hard requirement is everything is C++ now, and we have to make a strong case for even using `cstdio`.

Comment: The actual link is http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/iomanip.html . Yet the iostream manipulators should be avoided because they change the internal state of the stream conversion engine. What an ugly API!

Comment: Note: `"%zp"` is not standard C.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Boost Format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/)? It seems to be just what you need.

Comment: Changed the accepted answer as the second one was a bit more in-line with what I needed to accomplish. Thank you. +1 to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can cout even generate such a string in a simple manner with just one
>   line of code, or should I use sprintf to prepare my strings and then
>   feed them to cout?

---

I agree that sprintf() is not C++.  It merely provides some manner of backward compatibility ... i.e. it has been provided specifically so that you can post-pone the conversion (of c to c++) and that technical debt to later in your schedule.

---

Here is a code sample from when I 'fixed' a log to be C++. (I left in the sprintf() to help document the new C++ code.)

```
  //retVal = ::sprintf(buff1, "%08llx  %2d:%02d:%02d,  %05llu.%03llu:  ",
  //            a_pid, hr, min, sec, (ms_of_day / 1000), (rt_ms % 1000));
  // use stringstream formatting, not sprintf
  buff1 << std::dec << std::setfill('0')  << std::setw(8) << a_pid << " "
        << std::setfill('0')  << std::setw(2) << hr   << ":"
        << std::setfill('0')  << std::setw(2) << min  << ":"
        << std::setfill('0')  << std::setw(2) << sec  << ",  "
        << std::setfill('0')  << std::setw(5) << (ms_of_day / 1000) 
        << "."
        << std::setfill('0')  << std::setw(3) << (ms_of_day % 1000) 
        << ":  ";
```

I only had to do this once.

In a lot of ways, I do not miss the 'unsafe-type' style of sprintf.

---

If there is something special you do often, you might also consider creating something like the following.

```
std::string ssprintf0x08x(std::string label, void*  ptr)
{
   std::stringstream ss;

   ss << label << "0x"
      << std::hex << std::internal << std::setw(8) 
      << std::setfill('0')
      << reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(ptr);

   return (ss.str());
}
```

I only had to implement this one time.

---

Answer to question:

> Can cout even generate such a string in a simple manner with just one
>   line of code?

Yes. Of course.

C++ stream output has a learning curve, but it leads you to a type-safe approach for text output.

And, perhaps you are realizing, one line of code can be quite long.

Comment: *Once* is not enough: the first code fragment is bogus: `std::hex` should be used for `a_pid` and `std::dec` for the other fields.  But the way these maipulators modify the state of the iostream is despicable.  This is an unacceptable price to pay for type safety.

Comment: @chqrlie - I appreciate your opinion.  I did this particular sample before I knew enough about that particular issue (of state 'stickyness'), maybe a decade ago.  I no longer find state 'sticky' issues a surprise, nor difficult to recognize and handle.

Comment: There are several other problems with my (commented out) sprintf() above -- the biggest being: how many bytes does one allow in the buff used by sprintf().  Each of my team had an opinion, most did not want to log much.  Still, the log buffer grew until finally, for that embedded system, we decided to truncate each over-sized log entry ... and every one adapted to the restriction.  With string stream, we captured any size entry, and added options for reporting.

Comment: And:  all those sprintf() modifiers(?), the 08ll, or 05ll in front of x or d or u.  It always took me an unreasonable effort to get them correct.  I no longer remember why - was it something about the way the compiler messages numbered the parameters?  I am done with that.

Comment: If you think the complexities of output formatting are better addressed by these manipulators, good for you... btw you should use `uintptr_t` in  `reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(ptr)` for portablity.

Comment: @chqrlie - hey now, don't put words in my mouth ... I did not say iomanip was better, just different.

Comment: @chqrlie - Thanks for the tip about uintptr_t.  I had never heard of it till now.  I recently changed to 64 bit ubuntu, and I am discovering many uint32_t that no longer compile.  But that is fine, at least the compiler helps me find them.  And of course, I made most of those mistakes prior to 2011.

Answer (score 2):

Question the requirements!

`printf` works fine in `C++`, proper use of compiler warnings prevent type inconsistencies. The `C++` formatting alternative is too complicated and error prone: it is so easy to leave the stream formatting in a different state than upon entry.

If you really need to use `cout`, use `snprintf()` to format the log entry and shift the formatted string to `cout`.

Comment: Good call!  An exception would be if `printf()` was excessively or output an embedded `'\0'` which would complicate things - but that is not likely with OP's `"%3.4f %d %zp %5.8f"`. (Unless `DBL_MAX %f` exceeds `snprintf()` buffer)